# MySQL - simple query sometime cases infinite loop & continuously incrementing number of rows_fetched

Tags: mysql, innodb

I’ve been struggling last 4 weeks figuring out why a query intermittently execute forever on Docker Mysql Percona Distribution ([percona:8.0.32-24](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/percona/8.0.32-24/images/sha256-5332a2dd238486f597566403403410e85cc4438f11f317f65458105be00feeba?context=explore), empty my.cnf). This postscript query runs after the import of multiple CSVs generated from a data-mining algorithm using MySQL Shell. Half of the time, it successfully executes in 2-3 seconds.
Otherwise, stalls and goes into an **infinite loop** (2+ days) with a **continuously incrementing number of rows_fetched** ([fig1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu6Jo.png)), even after the correct number of rows_inserted is displayed. Why is this query running for so long, and what is it reading table endlessly (high rows_fetched)?

```
CREATE TABLE algo_rca_rule_metric (
 key varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
 rule_id int unsigned NOT NULL,
 context_id int unsigned NOT NULL,
 value double NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (key,value,rule_id),
 KEY key_rule_id (rule_id,key,value)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

** 2 Metrics (confidence and support) get inserted before the query runs:

```
INSERT INTO algo_rca_rule_metric
SELECT
   'confidence_order' AS 'key',
   metric_confidence.rule_id,
   metric_confidence.context_id,
   row_number() over (ORDER BY metric_confidence.value ASC, metric_support.value ASC) AS 'value'
FROM algo_rca_rule_metric metric_confidence
LEFT JOIN algo_rca_rule_metric metric_support ON (metric_confidence.rule_id = metric_support.rule_id AND metric_support.key = 'rule_support')
WHERE metric_confidence.key = 'confidence';
```

Same behaviour observed without the INSERT.

*See explain statement (*[fig3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fRTw.png)). When the infinite loop occurs, the following is observed:

- `show processlist`: query is marked as `status = "Execute"`.
- `show engine innodb status`: query nowhere to be found in transaction section.
- `select * from sys.schema_table_statistics WHERE table_schema = 'DB_NAME'` rows_fetched output for  seems to growing indefinitely. (See [fig1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou1Cs.png) not working, [fig4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkuop.png) working, both are executed against the identical data).

Any help or insights would be a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Put `value` last in the PK:

```
PRIMARY KEY key_rule_id (rule_id, key, value),
KEY (key, value, rule_id)
```

Note that `322` comes from 2+4*80, implying that it is using only one column.  (Ditto for `const`.)

- 2 byte length field
- 4 bytes (max) per utf8mb4 character
- 80 characters in declaration

That does not mean that a full 322 bytes are allocated, but it is the 'worst case'.

Comment: Where does the 4 come from in 2+4*80?

Comment: I elaborated...